# Array filter returning an empty array in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I am trying to filter an array of objects in ReactJs. However when I try filtering the objects by a userId, the array returns as empty.

To make sure that my favorites prop has updated, I console logged all relavent info in my componentDidMount() function. The console.log showed that my favorites prop was indeed an array with objects inside of it.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log(this.props.favorites);
        console.log(this.props.favorites[0].userId);
        console.log(this.filterFavorites());
    }

    filterFavorites() {
        return this.props.favorites.filter((favorite) => {
            return favorite.userId === this.props.currentUserId;
        });
    }
```

However I expected an array returned with the objects filtered by the current user's id. Instead I got an empty array

Comment: you are sure that `favorite.userId === this.props.currentUserId` will return true in the loop?

Comment: Maybe `currentUserId` is the wrong type

Comment: are you correctly binding `filterFavorites` to the class instance so you have access to props? [**Your code executes just fine**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-ncvtq), so either you aren't binding or you dont have the values you expect you do

Comment: @Aluan thanks, I just realized currentUserId was not properly set in mapStateToProps and was returning as undefined so the comparison always returned false.

Answer (score -2):

By default, filter doesn't have `this` bound to anything; it's `undefined`, you have to pass the this reference after the function body.

[W3FTW](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

```
    filterFavorites() {
        return this.props.favorites.filter((favorite) => {
            return favorite.userId === this.props.currentUserId;
        }, this);
    }
```

Comment: This is not true, because an arrow function does the binding for you.